# Lock statement exception c#

Tags: c#, exception, locking

I have a method Add and unit test ParallelAddAmountTest. Everything works well but lock block have an exception. It is bad. How to refactor method Add?

```
 public void Add(int amountToAdd)
        {
            lock (balanceLock)
            {
                if (Amount + amountToAdd > MaxAllowedAmount)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Cannot add the specified amount: the sum exceeds account limit.");
                }
                
                if (Amount + amountToAdd <= MaxAllowedAmount)
                {
                    AddAmountAndEmulateTransactionDelay(amountToAdd);
                }
            }
        }
```

Unit test for the method Add:

```
public void ParallelAddAmountTest()
        {
            var balance = new Balance(90000);

            var withdrawTenThTask = Task.Run(() => balance.Add(10000));
            var withdrawFiveThTask = Task.Run(() => balance.Add(10000));

            Assert.Throws(
                typeof(AggregateException),
                () => Task.WaitAll(withdrawFiveThTask, withdrawTenThTask),
                "Cannot add the specified amount: the sum exceeds account limit.");          

            Assert.AreEqual(100000, balance.Amount);
        }
```

Comment: What's wrong with this, exactly? Throwing inside a `lock` is fine

Comment: The exception is fine but you should avoid the `lock` statement if you can.

Comment: @canton7 I want to throw inside the method Add but unit test don't work.

Comment: What's wrong with the unit test?

Comment: Note that the AggregateException which `Task.WaitAll` throws won't have the message "Cannot add the specified amount...", it will be "One or more Exceptions occurred" (or something similar, can't remember exactly), then the InnerException will have the message "Cannot add the specified amount..."

Comment: " but lock block have an exception. " and "but unit test don't work" - please be **specific**; what **exactly** happens? we're not psychic, nor can we reach over the internet and press "play" and watch the test run

Comment: Your Testrunner should show you what the problem is. Something like the ErrorMessage do not match when asserting presumably. No need to guess here.

Comment: What is `AddAmountAndEmulateTransactionDelay`? Is it by chance an async method? Please provide a full [mre].

Comment: @canton7 When I throw inside a lock statement  unit test is fine. When I throw outside the lock statement test is false.

Comment: @Pavel.Shymko but the code you've shown use throws inside the lock, so... it is fine? so: what is the question?

Comment: You *can* move the throw outside of the lock statement, but you have to be careful -- in particular the `if (Amount + amountToAdd > MaxAllowedAmount)` test still needs to happen inside the lock of course. But there's no need to.